# How can I get "EOFEroor" in Python while taking multiple inputs from users?

Tags: python, eof, valueerror, try-except, multiple-input

I'm trying to get multiple inputs from users and break the loop by End of File(EOF) error.

```
while True:
try:
    n, l, c = map(int,input().split())

except EOFError:
    break
```

But when the user gives multiple inputs and then press Enter the ValuEroor warning has come.

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

In this scenario, Is there any way to get EOFEroor to break the loop and avoid ValueEoor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get `EOFError` if the user presses CTRL-D. Just add `ValueError` to the caught exceptions:

```py
except (EOFError, ValueError):
```

or, if needed to be handled differently:

```py
except EOFError:
    ...
except ValueError:
    ...
```

You will need it anyway in case the user enters a string that can't be converted to `int`.